# Regex, stop before a backslash caracter?

Tags: regex

i want to use regex for replace a string in a file in powershell, this is the regex:

```
=.*\\app\\client\\.*\\
```

I applied this regex on that string:

HOME= C:\app\client\Administrateur\product

And i want this result:

= C:\app\client\Administrateur

But I have this result:

= C:\app\client\Administrateur\

How to say to regex i want to stop before the next backslash ?

Comment: You  could match not a forward slash at the end `=.*\\app\\client\\[^\\]*` https://regex101.com/r/HQ9PcJ/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern `=.*\\app\\client\\.*\\` will match the last occurrence of `\app\client\` and will then match until the last occurrence of the forward slash.

To match what comes after `app\client\` but not include the last backslash you could use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) matching not a backslash:

```
=.*\\app\\client\\[^\\]*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HQ9PcJ/1)

If the `.*` part at the start can not contain a backslash, this would be another option to prevent needless backtracking because the `.*` would first match until the end of the string:

```
=[^\\]*\\app\\client\\[^\\]*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/819uhU/1/)